# Matter.js - how to constrain movement and mouse interaction to a single axis?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

Using Matter.js, how can I constrain movement of a body to a single axis (i.e. only the X axis)? I'd like to be able to make it so a body can only be dragged horizontally within a set boundary.

I'm trying to create an abacus and allow the user to flick beads around along a fixed bar. Laying it all out is fine, but I can't for the life of me work out how to restrict the movement like this.

I've tried setting a fixed body above and below the beads, which works to an extent but when I add MouseConstraint the dragging behaviour ignores this altogether and you can drag right through it.

I've also tried using the beforeUpdate event to "reset" the Y value of each bead before it gets drawn (using Body.setPosition). This sort of works to an extent, however the Y value kind of drifts back in to alignment and I'd rather it not deviate at all if that makes sense.

Is there a better way to accomplish this task? Can a body be told to "stick" to another body perhaps? That way I could create my bars and stick the beads to them.

Comment: I'm trying to tackle this issue now, can't seem to find a working solution. I've tried a standard [constraint](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Constraint.html) and tried to update the x-coordinate of it, but that doesn't work. There's no `constraint.setPosition` method, that only works on [Body](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#method_setPosition).

Comment: This is an interesting problem, and I realize it's super old, but showing a [mcve] would help make it easier to understand the use case and attempts so someone can post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `setPosition` in an `afterUpdate` event handler to force the body to a certain position on one axis.

Here's a proof of concept (please excuse the hardcoded values):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
engine.gravity.y = 0;
const verticalBox = {
  w: 40,
  h: 20,
  pinX: 150,
  body: Matter.Bodies.rectangle(100, 100, 40, 20, {
    frictionAir: 0.6,
    density: 1,
    restitution: 1,
  }),
  elem: document.querySelector(".vertical-box"),
};
const horizontalBox = {
  w: 40,
  h: 20,
  pinY: 150,
  body: Matter.Bodies.rectangle(100, 100, 40, 20, {
    frictionAir: 0.6,
    density: 1,
    restitution: 1,
  }),
  elem: document.querySelector(".horizontal-box"),
};
const walls = [
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(200, -200, 400, 400, {isStatic: true}),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(-200, 200, 400, 400, {isStatic: true}),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(200, 500, 400, 400, {isStatic: true}),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(500, 200, 400, 400, {isStatic: true}),
];
const boxes = [...Array(100)].map(() => Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
  Math.random() * 400,
  Math.random() * 400,
  Math.random() * 20 + 10,
  Math.random() * 20 + 10,
  {
    angle: Math.random() * Math.PI,
    frictionAir: 0.05,
    restitution: 0.6,
    density: 0.2,
  }
));
const repositionDOMBox = box => {
  const {x, y} = box.body.position;
  box.elem.style.top = `${y - box.h / 2}px`;
  box.elem.style.left = `${x - box.w / 2}px`;
  box.elem.style.transform = `rotate(${box.body.angle}rad)`;
};
const renderBoxOnCanvas = body => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  body.vertices.forEach(e => ctx.lineTo(e.x, e.y));
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
};
const mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
  element: document.body,
});
Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, [
  mouseConstraint,
  horizontalBox.body,
  verticalBox.body,
  ...walls,
  ...boxes,
]);
Matter.Events.on(engine, "afterUpdate", () => {
  const {y} = verticalBox.body.position;
  Matter.Body.setPosition(
    verticalBox.body,
    {
      x: verticalBox.pinX,

      // optionally clamp to walls
      y: y > 290 ? 290 : y < 0 ? 0 : y,
      //y,
    }
  );
  const {x} = horizontalBox.body.position;
  Matter.Body.setPosition(
    horizontalBox.body,
    {
      // optionally clamp to walls
      x: x > 280 ? 280 : x < 0 ? 0 : x,
      //x,

      y: horizontalBox.pinY,
    }
  );

  // optionally prevent rotation
  Matter.Body.setAngle(verticalBox.body, 0);
  Matter.Body.setAngle(horizontalBox.body, 0);
});
(function rerender() {
  requestAnimationFrame(rerender);
  Matter.Engine.update(engine);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.moveTo(0, 150);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.moveTo(150, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(150, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
  repositionDOMBox(verticalBox);
  repositionDOMBox(horizontalBox);
  boxes.forEach(renderBoxOnCanvas);
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  user-select: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.vertical-box {
  background: #191;
  cursor: row-resize;
}
.horizontal-box {
  background: #e71;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
canvas {
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
<div class="box vertical-box">↕</div>
<div class="box horizontal-box">↔</div>
<canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

As a rule of thumb, though, using `setPosition` to override the physics engine creates some annoying edge cases that often need to be dealt with to preserve realism, so it's dangerous territory in MJS. How to deal with these cases is use-case specific.

In the example here, I've taken an extra step to prevent the axis-constrained bodies' angles from changing, which makes collision between the two boxes a bit unrealistic. I've also clamped the axis-constrained boxes to the walls to prevent them from being dragged off canvas.

One workaround for the constrained body collision is to use a static core that tracks the axis-constrained body on each tick to prevent overlap as described [here](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/552#issuecomment-355015992).

That said, in many cases, the axis-constrained body may not need to deal with collisions on bodies pinned to another axis, as in an abacus app. Although, for the abacus app, you may need to deal with beads on the same axis jumping over each other when dragged with the mouse; this could be dealt with by temporarily creating large invisible static bodies over the areas the body shouldn't be allowed to go that only collide with the dragged body.

Using circular bodies and avoiding mouse interaction, which is notoriously glitchy, can also help mitigate issues.

See also:

- [What is the best way to allow movement along a single axis? #552](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/552)
- [Prevent force-dragging bodies through other bodies with MatterJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59321773/prevent-force-dragging-bodies-through-other-bodies-with-matterjs).