# Prevent force-dragging bodies through other bodies with MatterJS

Tags: javascript, physics, matter.js

I'm using MatterJs for a physics based game and have not found a solution for the problem of preventing bodies being force-dragged by the mouse through other bodies. If you drag a body into another body, the body being dragged can force itself into and through the other body. I'm looking for a reliable way to prevent them from intersecting. You can observe this effect in any MatterJS demo by selecting a body with the mouse, and trying to force it through another body. Here is a typical example:

[image]

https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#staticFriction

Unfortunately this breaks any games or simulations depending on drag-and-drop.
I have attempted numerous solutions, such as breaking the mouse constraint when a collision occurs, or reducing constraint stiffness, but nothing which works reliably.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: I don't understand the force-dragged wording. Do you mean your dragged body should go through any other bodies?

Comment: No, it means the dragged body should be prevented from going through any other bodies.

Comment: @d13 Could you add an animation showing the issue? Since there seems to be some confusion based on the wording...

Comment: @Ghost added...

Comment: @d13 That makes things clearer..... this is a tricky one

Answer (score 13):

I think that the best answer here would be a significant overhaul to the `Matter.Resolver` module to implement predictive avoidance of physical conflicts between any bodies. Anything short of that is *guaranteed* to fail under certain circumstances. That being said here are two "solutions" which, in reality, are just partial solutions. They are outlined below.

---

## Solution 1   (Update)

This solution has several advantages:

- It is more concise than **Solution 2**
- It creates a smaller computational footprint than **Solution 2**
- The drag behavior is not interrupted the way it is in **Solution 2**
- It can be non-destructively combined with **Solution 2**

The idea behind this approach is to resolve the paradox of what happens "*when an unstoppable force meets an immovable object*" by rendering the force stoppable. This is enabled by the `Matter.Event` `beforeUpdate`, which allows the absolute velocity and impulse (or rather `positionImpulse`, which isn't really physical impulse) in each direction to be constrained to within user-defined bounds.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('world')
    var mouseNull = document.getElementById('mouseNull')
    var engine = Matter.Engine.create();
    var world = engine.world;
    var render = Matter.Render.create({    element: document.body, canvas: canvas,
                 engine: engine, options: { width: 800, height: 800,
                     background: 'transparent',showVelocity: true }});
    var body = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(400, 500, 200, 60, { isStatic: true}), 
        size = 50, counter = -1;
     
    var stack = Matter.Composites.stack(350, 470 - 6 * size, 1, 6, 
                                        0, 0, function(x, y) {
     return Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, size * 2, size, {
         slop: 0, friction: 1,    frictionStatic: Infinity });
    });
    Matter.World.add(world, [ body, stack,
     Matter.Bodies.rectangle(400, 0, 800, 50, { isStatic: true }),
     Matter.Bodies.rectangle(400, 600, 800, 50, { isStatic: true }),
     Matter.Bodies.rectangle(800, 300, 50, 600, { isStatic: true }),
     Matter.Bodies.rectangle(0, 300, 50, 600, { isStatic: true })
    ]);

    Matter.Events.on(engine, 'beforeUpdate', function(event) {
     counter += 0.014;
     if (counter < 0) { return; }
     var px = 400 + 100 * Math.sin(counter);
     Matter.Body.setVelocity(body, { x: px - body.position.x, y: 0 });
     Matter.Body.setPosition(body, { x: px, y: body.position.y });
     if (dragBody != null) {
        if (dragBody.velocity.x > 25.0) {
            Matter.Body.setVelocity(dragBody, {x: 25, y: dragBody.velocity.y });
        }
        if (dragBody.velocity.y > 25.0) {
            Matter.Body.setVelocity(dragBody, {x: dragBody.velocity.x, y: 25 });
        }
        if (dragBody.positionImpulse.x > 25.0) {
            dragBody.positionImpulse.x = 25.0;
        }
        if (dragBody.positionImpulse.y > 25.0) {
            dragBody.positionImpulse.y = 25.0;
        }
    }
    });

    var mouse = Matter.Mouse.create(render.canvas),
     mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(engine, { mouse: mouse,
         constraint: { stiffness: 0.1, render: { visible: false }}});
     
    var dragBody = null


    Matter.Events.on(mouseConstraint, 'startdrag', function(event) {
     dragBody = event.body;
    });
    
    Matter.World.add(world, mouseConstraint);
    render.mouse = mouse;
    Matter.Engine.run(engine);
    Matter.Render.run(render);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="world"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.10.0/matter.js"></script>
```

In the example I am restricting the `velocity` and `positionImpulse` in `x` and `y` to a maximum magnitude of `25.0`. The result is shown below

[image]

As you can see, it is possible to be quite violent in dragging the bodies and they will not pass through one another. This is what sets this approach apart from others: most other potential solutions fail when the user is sufficiently violent with their dragging.

The only shortcoming I have encountered with this method is that it is possible to use a non-static body to hit another non-static body hard enough to give it sufficient velocity to the point where the `Resolver` module will fail to detect the collision and allow the second body to pass through other bodies. (In the static friction example the required velocity is around `50.0`, I've only managed to do this successfully one time, and consequently I do not have an animation depicting it).

---

## Solution 2

This is an additional solution, fair warning though: it is not straightforward.

In broad terms the way this works is to check if the body being dragged, `dragBody`, has collided with a static body and if the mouse has since moved too far without `dragBody` following. If it detects that the separation between the mouse and `dragBody` has become too large it removes the [`Matter.js`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/files/src_core_Mouse.js.html#l131) `mouse.mousemove` event listener from `mouse.element` and replaces it with a different mousemove function, `mousemove()`. This function checks if the mouse has returned to within a given proximity of the center of the body. Unfortunately I couldn't get the built-in `Matter.Mouse._getRelativeMousePosition()` method to work properly so I had to include it directly (someone more knowledgeable than me in Javascript will have to figure that one out). Finally, if a `mouseup` event is detected it switches back to the normal `mousemove` listener.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('world')
    var mouseNull = document.getElementById('mouseNull')
    var engine = Matter.Engine.create();
    var world = engine.world;
    var render = Matter.Render.create({ element: document.body, canvas: canvas,
                 engine: engine, options: { width: 800, height: 800,
                     background: 'transparent',showVelocity: true }});
    var body = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(400, 500, 200, 60, { isStatic: true}), 
        size = 50, counter = -1;
     
    var stack = Matter.Composites.stack(350, 470 - 6 * size, 1, 6, 
                                        0, 0, function(x, y) {
     return Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, size * 2, size, {
         slop: 0.5, friction: 1,    frictionStatic: Infinity });
    });
    Matter.World.add(world, [ body, stack,
     Matter.Bodies.rectangle(400, 0, 800, 50, { isStatic: true }),
     Matter.Bodies.rectangle(400, 600, 800, 50, { isStatic: true }),
     Matter.Bodies.rectangle(800, 300, 50, 600, { isStatic: true }),
     Matter.Bodies.rectangle(0, 300, 50, 600, { isStatic: true })
    ]);

    Matter.Events.on(engine, 'beforeUpdate', function(event) {
     counter += 0.014;
     if (counter < 0) { return; }
     var px = 400 + 100 * Math.sin(counter);
     Matter.Body.setVelocity(body, { x: px - body.position.x, y: 0 });
     Matter.Body.setPosition(body, { x: px, y: body.position.y });
    });

    var mouse = Matter.Mouse.create(render.canvas),
     mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(engine, { mouse: mouse,
         constraint: { stiffness: 0.2, render: { visible: false }}});
     
    var dragBody, overshoot = 0.0, threshold = 50.0, loc, dloc, offset, 
    bodies = Matter.Composite.allBodies(world), moveOn = true;
    getMousePosition = function(event) {
     var element = mouse.element, pixelRatio = mouse.pixelRatio, 
        elementBounds = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
        rootNode = (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || 
                    document.body),
        scrollX = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : 
                   rootNode.scrollLeft,
        scrollY = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : 
                   rootNode.scrollTop,
        touches = event.changedTouches, x, y;
     if (touches) {
         x = touches[0].pageX - elementBounds.left - scrollX;
         y = touches[0].pageY - elementBounds.top - scrollY;
     } else {
         x = event.pageX - elementBounds.left - scrollX;
         y = event.pageY - elementBounds.top - scrollY;
     }
     return { 
         x: x / (element.clientWidth / (element.width || element.clientWidth) *
            pixelRatio) * mouse.scale.x + mouse.offset.x,
         y: y / (element.clientHeight / (element.height || element.clientHeight) *
            pixelRatio) * mouse.scale.y + mouse.offset.y
     };
    };     
    mousemove = function() {
     loc = getMousePosition(event);
     dloc = dragBody.position;
     overshoot = ((loc.x - dloc.x)**2 + (loc.y - dloc.y)**2)**0.5 - offset;
     if (overshoot < threshold) {
         mouse.element.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
         mouse.element.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse.mousemove);
         moveOn = true;
     }
    }
    Matter.Events.on(mouseConstraint, 'startdrag', function(event) {
     dragBody = event.body;
     loc = mouse.position;
     dloc = dragBody.position;
     offset = ((loc.x - dloc.x)**2 + (loc.y - dloc.y)**2)**0.5;
     Matter.Events.on(mouseConstraint, 'mousemove', function(event) {
         loc = mouse.position;
         dloc = dragBody.position;
         for (var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {                      
             overshoot = ((loc.x - dloc.x)**2 + (loc.y - dloc.y)**2)**0.5 - offset;
             if (bodies[i] != dragBody && 
                 Matter.SAT.collides(bodies[i], dragBody).collided == true) {
                 if (overshoot > threshold) {
                     if (moveOn == true) {
                         mouse.element.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouse.mousemove);
                         mouse.element.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
                         moveOn = false;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     });
    });

    Matter.Events.on(mouseConstraint, 'mouseup', function(event) {
     if (moveOn == false){
         mouse.element.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
         mouse.element.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse.mousemove);
         moveOn = true;
     }
    });
    Matter.Events.on(mouseConstraint, 'enddrag', function(event) {
     overshoot = 0.0;
     Matter.Events.off(mouseConstraint, 'mousemove');
    });

    Matter.World.add(world, mouseConstraint);
    render.mouse = mouse;
    Matter.Engine.run(engine);
    Matter.Render.run(render);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="world"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.10.0/matter.js"></script>
```

After applying the event listener switching scheme the bodies now behave more like this

[image]

I have tested this *fairly* thoroughly, but I can't guarantee it will work in every case. It also bears noting that the `mouseup` event is not detected unless the mouse is within the canvas when it occurs - but this is true for any Matter.js `mouseup` detection so I didn't try to fix that.

If the velocity is sufficiently large, `Resolver` will fail to detect any collision, and since it lacks predictive prevention of this flavor of physical conflict, will allow the body to pass through, as shown here.

[image]

This can be resolved by combining with **Solution 1**.

One last note here, it is possible to apply this to only certain interactions (e.g. those between a static and a non-static body). Doing so is accomplished by changing

```js
if (bodies[i] != dragBody && Matter.SAT.collides(bodies[i], dragBody).collided == true) {
    //...
}
```

to (for e.g. static bodies)

```js
if (bodies[i].isStatic == true && bodies[i] != dragBody && 
    Matter.SAT.collides(bodies[i], dragBody).collided == true) {
    //...
}
```

---

### Failed solutions

In case any future users come across this question and find both solutions insufficient for their use case, here are some of the solutions I attempted which did **not** work. A guide of sorts for what not to do.

- Calling `mouse.mouseup` directly: object deleted immediately.
- Calling `mouse.mouseup` via `Event.trigger(mouseConstraint, 'mouseup', {mouse: mouse})`: overridden by `Engine.update`, behavior unchanged.
- Making the dragged object temporarily static: object deleted on returning to non-static (whether via `Matter.Body.setStatic(body, false)` or `body.isStatic = false`).
- Setting the force to `(0,0)` via `setForce` when approaching conflict:  object can still pass through, would need to be implemented in `Resolver` to actually work.
- Changing `mouse.element` to a different canvas via `setElement()` or by mutating `mouse.element` directly: object deleted immediately.
- Reverting object to last 'valid' position: still allows pass through,
- Change behavior via `collisionStart`: inconsistent collision detection still permits pass through with this method

---

Comment: Thanks so much for your contributions! I awarded you the bounty because even though your solution wasn't perfect, it definitely points the way forward and you put a huge amount of thought and time into this problem - Thank you!! I'm now certain that this problem is ultimately a feature-gap in MatterJS, and hopefully this discussion will contribute to a real solution in the future.

Comment: @d13 Thanks, I agree that the problem is ultimately in the underlying code but I'm glad I could get some semblance of solution(s)

Comment: This method stopped working after matter.js version 0.12.0

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to [issue 672](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/672) on their GitHub page which seems to suggest that this occurs due to a lack of Continuous Collision Detection (CCD).

An attempt to remedy this has been made and the code for it can be found [here](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/src/geometry/Bounds.js) but the issue is still open so it looks like you might need to edit the engine to build CCD into it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had considered this but I believe it is not a CCD problem but a problem of "What happens when an unstoppable force meets an unmovable obstacle?" Somehow I need to figure out how to neutralise the forces to prevent the bodies from intersecting.

Answer (score 0):

I would have managed the feature in another way:

- No "drag" (so no continuos align of dragpoint with offset Vs dragged object)
- On mouseDown the mouse pointer position give an oriented velocity vector for object to follow
- On mouseUp reset your velocity vector
- Let the matter simulation do the rest

Comment: Isn't that kinda how `matter.js` handles dragging bodies already? from [here](https://blog.alexandergottlieb.com/matter-js-the-missing-tutorial-70aafc06b167) *"...like a virtual spring that attaches to the mouse. When dragging ... the spring is attached [to the body] and pulls in the direction of mouse..."*

Comment: Setting only the velocity prevents dragging overlap, the sping forces the body through others.

Comment: This might actually point to a solution. If I understand correctly, it means not using MatterJS's built in MouseConstraint and setting the body's velocity manually based on the mouse's position. I'm not sure exactly how this would be implemented, however, so if anyone can post details on how align the body to the mouse's position, without using setPosition or a constraint, please do.

Comment: @d13 you'd still be relying on MatterJS's [`Resolver`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/files/src_collision_Resolver.js.html#l224) to decide what to do about colliding bodies - having looked through that code a fair bit I expect it would still decide to allow drag-through under many circumstances..... might work if you also implemented your own version of `solveVelocity` and `solvePosition` but at that point you're still manually doing what you want MatterJS to handle directly....

Answer (score -1):

To control collision when dragged you need to utilize [collision filter](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_collisionFilter) and [events](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Events.html).

Create bodies with default [collision filter mask](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_collisionFilter.mask) `0x0001`. Add catch `startdrag` and `enddrag` events and set different body [collision filter category](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_collisionFilter.category) to temporarily avoid collisions.

```
Matter.Events.on(mouseConstraint, 'startdrag', function(event) {
    event.body.collisionFilter.category = 0x0008; // move body to new category to avoid collision
});
Matter.Events.on(mouseConstraint, 'enddrag', function(event) {
     event.body.collisionFilter.category = 0x0001; // return body to default category to activate collision
});
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

  //Fetch our canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById('world');

  //Setup Matter JS
  var engine = Matter.Engine.create();
  var world = engine.world;
  var render = Matter.Render.create({
                                      canvas: canvas,
                                      engine: engine,
                                      options: {
                                        width: 800,
                                        height: 800,
                                        background: 'transparent',
                                        wireframes: false,
                                        showAngleIndicator: false
                                      }
                                    });

  //Add a ball
  const size = 50;
  const stack = Matter.Composites.stack(350, 470 - 6 * size, 1, 6, 0, 0, (x, y) => {
    return Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, size * 2, size, {
      collisionFilter: {
            mask: 0x0001,
      },
      slop: 0.5,
      friction: 1,
      frictionStatic: Infinity,
    });
  });

  Matter.World.add(engine.world, stack);

  //Add a floor
  var floor = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(250, 520, 500, 40, {
    isStatic: true, //An immovable object
    render: {
      visible: false
    }
  });
  Matter.World.add(world, floor);

  //Make interactive
  var mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(engine, { //Create Constraint
    element: canvas,

    constraint: {
      render: {
        visible: false
      },
      stiffness: 0.8
    }
  });
  Matter.World.add(world, mouseConstraint);

  // add events to listen drag
  Matter.Events.on(mouseConstraint, 'startdrag', function (event) {
    event.body.collisionFilter.category = 0x0008; // move body to new category to avoid collision
  });
  Matter.Events.on(mouseConstraint, 'enddrag', function (event) {
    event.body.collisionFilter.category = 0x0001; // return body to default category to activate collision
  });

  //Start the engine
  Matter.Engine.run(engine);
  Matter.Render.run(render);

});
```

```html
<canvas id="world"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.10.0/matter.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you excellent demo! I'm actually trying to achieve the opposite effect: I need to prevent bodies from intersecting when one is dragged into another.

Comment: Sorry If I misunderstood the issue. Can you clarify what you mean by preventing bodies from intersecting? Are you trying to prevent dragging through other objects when force applied?

Comment: In that case it's open issue and can't be done without hard-coding to implement CCD. Take a look: https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/5